# Error running Tapku demo project

Tags: calendar, simulator, demo, tapku

I'm try to run TapKu iOS demo project downloaded from:
https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary/branches

I build without errors but when it comes to be installed on the simulator, I get this error message:

```
[AppDelegate_iPhone window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9b7ad90
2012-12-03 17:05:13.478 unviersaldemo[94132:13d03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate_iPhone window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9b7ad90'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1a44012 0x1429e7e 0x1acf4bd 0x143d7ea 0x1a33cf9 0x1a3394e 0x3da78 0x2bcc 0x4807b7 0x480da7 0x481fab 0x493315 0x49424b 0x485cf8 0x237fdf9 0x237fad0 0x19b9bf5 0x19b9962 0x19eabb6 0x19e9f44 0x19e9e1b 0x4817da 0x48365c 0x2b36 0x2925 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added:

```
@interface AppDelegate_iPhone : TKAppDelegate <UIApplicationDelegate> {   
    UIWindow *window;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *window;
```

in the AppDelegate_iPhone.h file

and

```
@synthesize window;
```

in the AppDelegate_iPhone.m file.
Works for me.

Comment: Ok it runs but when I try to play with it I got this error:
2012-12-05 10:58:19.350 unviersaldemo[98678:13d03] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch.Anyway I accept your solution cos it fixes my first problem :)